# WebView to read and zoom image not zoom correclty

Tags: java, android, image, webview, zooming

I'm using a WebView to load a local image, and i need to zoom it, but i have a problem, it has the +/- to zoom but they does not work, and also with 2 finger i can't zoom (the guides that i seen zoom also in that way). Zoom a little bit only with a double click.

My webview (that is in a scroll view):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/webview" />
```

The Java Class Code:

```
WebView wv = null;
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        wv.setInitialScale(1);
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_res/drawable/map.jpg");
```

The image correctly load with the scale 1 entirely (not already zoommed), but i can't zoom it with the 2 finger. Where ar emy errors?
Thank you so much

Comment: Try this?? 
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false); It will hide the zoom controls and only pinch zoom will work.

Comment: Also don't use this if you want to use zoom function `wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);`

Comment: if i do that the image disappear

Answer (score 0):

Remove wv.setInitialScale(1);

This will make the image fit int eh visible screen. Then you'll be able to zoom in

Comment: if i remove the seinitial scale, the image starts zoomed in at the maximum level of zoom

Comment: Any specific reason for using it inside scrollview?

Comment: I need to put a long text view above the webview, but also take off the scrollview and the text, it does not change

Comment: Can you try removing scrollview and adding this line

**wv.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);**